# Paypal IPN causing a problem

Tags: ce-1.6.2.0

I am having an issue with Paypal sending IPN messages to my Magento 1.6.2 store a short time (30 minutes or so) after an order has been completed.
When the message is received, the order is marked as "Processing" again.
The problem here is that these orders are automatically downloaded into our backoffice Sage 200 system every 15 minutes, and marked as "Exported" in Magento at that time, so that the export schedule doesn't download them twice, and therefore create a duplicate order in Sage 200 (it only downloads orders marked as "Processing").

It doesn't happen to all orders, so I'm not sure why it happens at all?
Any pointers on how to debug, and more importantly, prevent this from happening, would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I would say this is a bug of your sage export module.

When you export the order, it is not yet paid. How does sage know, when the order was paid?

Therefore you habe two ways to debug this (if you ask me)

1. add a flag instead of a status change to the order to mark the exported orders (you still don't know whether it was paid)
2. You change the export to only export order which are processing (and whatever other status you have for paid orders)

Comment: No. 2 would be my recommendation...Don't export order that could be cancelled or are otherwise not paid.  We manually capture payment, so if we were using this method, we would only export "Complete", or "Partialship" orders